# Output merge file representing modifications

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a svn and I sometimes i pick a couple of **non-sequential** revision numbers and i merge them into another branch.

I would like to output a 'unified' merge file output that can be reviewed by multiple people, but not actually do the merge and I do not want to 'revert' it either.

I need a 'cmd' type command like 'svn merge rev1,rev2 > mergeOutput.txt'

and then the mergeOutput.txt should contain the changes in a unified way, like right click a revision in tortoisesvn and -> 'Show changes in unified way'.

The key here is that my revisions that I merge are non sequential, so a 'svn patch' would not work because the 'svn patch' only accepts sequantial revisions.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this could work:

```
$ cd TARGET_WCPATH

$ pwd
TARGET_WCPATH

$ svn merge --dry-run SOURCE1@REV1 SOURCE2@REV2 | svn diff SOURCE1@REV1 TARGET@HEAD > mergeOutput.txt
```

From `svn help merge`:

> --dry-run: try operation but make no changes
>
> Two source URLs are specified, identifying two trees on the same
>   branch or on different branches. The trees are compared and the
>   difference from SOURCE1@REV1 to SOURCE2@REV2 is applied to the working
>   copy of the target branch at TARGET_WCPATH. The target branch may be
>   the same as one or both sources, or different again. The three
>   branches involved can be completely unrelated.
>
> TARGET_WCPATH is a working copy path; if omitted, '.' is generally
>   assumed.
>
> SOURCE1 and/or SOURCE2 can also be specified as a working copy path,
>   in which case the merge source URL is derived from the working copy.

For `svn diff` you can use any of these formats:

1. svn diff OLD-URL[@OLDREV] NEW-URL[@NEWREV]
2. svn diff OLD-URL[@OLDREV] NEW-PATH[@NEWREV]
3. svn diff OLD-PATH[@OLDREV] NEW-URL[@NEWREV]

Where SOURCE1 and TARGET in the svn diff can either be a URL or a path according to the formats above.